# Extrema function of two variables problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

A rectangular box with a square base is to be constructed from material that costs 9 dollars per $ft^2$ for the bottom, 7 dollars per $ft^2$ for the top, and 4 dollars per $ft^2$ for the sides. Find the box of greatest volume that can be constructed for $150. Round your answer to 2 decimals.

I have no idea where to start. I believe you would need to have your volume=lwh, but would you also need the surface area?

Answer (score 0):

If we let $x,y$ and $z$ be the lengths of the edges of the box in each direction, then the volume $V=xyz$.

But we've been told that the base is square, i.e. two of those lengths are the same, so we can now say that $x=z$, and so the volume, as a function of $x$ and $y$, is $V(x,y)=x^2y$, where $x^2$ is the base, and $y$ the height.

Our goal is to maximize $V$, with our given constraints. We can see that the cost of having a base of area $x^2$ is $9x^2$. The top, which has identical area, is also $9x^2$.

The area of a side face is one base length times the height, but since both the base lengths are identical, all the 4 side faces have area $xy$. The cost of one side, similar to before, is $4xy$.

So, we have two bases, and 4 sides, whose cost is 150 dollars. Therefore we can say $18x^2+16xy=150$.

Now we have put a constraint on the volume of the box. Using Lagrange multipliers, or any techniques you know, can you take it from here?

Comment: so is the given constraint yx^2? This is what confused me before

Comment: That $18x^2+16xy=150$. That limits the possible values of $x$ and $y$. When you learned about Lagrange multipliers, were tou not told of needing to have some constraint or limitation on x and y of the form $f(x,y)=c$ before you can do anything?

Comment: The function you are trying to optimise is $V(x,y)=x^2y$ , the volume of the box. $18x^2+16xy=150$ is the constraint. Do you understand how Lagrange Multipliers work?

Comment: yea, i get it now, for some reason i was getting confused. Thanks!!